# Does this equation have any natural solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

I've got this equation:

$$2^{x_1}+2^{x_2}-2^{x_3}=2^y$$

Besides the trivial solutions ($x_1=x_2=x_3=y$), does it have any other natural solution for given natural y?

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,x_2)$ works, too.

Comment: Check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) and fix your post.

Comment: I doubt it. Consider the binary representation of the LHS vs the RHS.

Comment: in $2^a + 2^b = 2^c + 2^d$ in positive $a,b,c,d$  we demand that $b$ be the minimum.  Dividing through by $2^b$  gives $2^\alpha  + 1 = 2^\beta + 2^\gamma$  with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0$    If $\alpha \neq 0$ we must have the minimum of $\beta, \gamma$  to be zero as well...

Comment: By "natural solution" do you mean "solution in natural numbers"? (Non-negative integers.)

Comment: @WillJagy Is it proven?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the binary representation of the LHS vs the RHS. Suppose $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all different. If $x_3$ is biggest, your LHS is negative, so there are no solutions. Wherever else $x_3$ appears, subtracting $2^{x_3}$ will not decrease the number of $1$s in the binary expansion. Indeed if it's $k$ steps below $x_1$ but above $x_2$ (say), the number of $1$s increases by $k-1$ (by carrying). So you have at least two $1$s, but the RHS has one (contradiction).

So some of them are equal. By symmetry, $x_1 = x_3$ and $x_2 = x_3$ are the same case; they give a unique solution for $y$ (the non-cancelling exponent).

If $x_1=x_2$ then you have the equation $2^{x_1 + 1} - 2^{x_3} = 2^y$. By the logic above $x_3$ and $x_1+1$ must be adjacent - so $x_3 = x_1$, and you have your family of trivial solutions.

Comment: So you say that there's only the trivial solution?

Comment: @MarcusRost What part of the answer are you struggling to understand?

Comment: Now I understand. Let me pose another question. If x1=x3, or x2=x3 what are the unique solutions then?

Comment: @MarcusRost If $x_1 = x_3$, then they cancel out, and the equation becomes $2^{x_2} = 2^{y}$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: Ahhhh. Now I got it. Thanks. It's simple. I just thought the wrong way around :D