# Four integers such that the sum of every pair is a power of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Numberphile Youtube channel just made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPoh5C9CcI8) telling us about an open question regarding natural numbers and the powers of two.

In a nutshell, it states that there are no 4 integers whose sum of each two pairs is a power of two.

Let's start with a simpler example with 3 such numbers:

$-1,\ 3\ $ and $5$.

$$-1 + 3 = 2,\ {-1} + 5 = 4 = 2^{2},\ 3+5=8=2^{3}$$
While it's easy to find examples with 3 numbers, finding examples with 4 numbers is not so easy.

In the video, Neil Sloane states that it's an open question, and the best solution known so far has 4 pairs. I thought it looks like a fun problem to play around with so I've written it in formal math:

Let $x,\ y,\ z,\ q \in \mathbb{Z}$ for the sake of nontriviality assume they are different. And right $a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ e,\ f \in \mathbb{N}$ some given constants.

Well, we have the following equation system:

$$ x+y=2^a\ [1] $$
$$ x+z=2^b\ [2] $$
$$ x+q=2^c\ [3] $$
$$ y+z=2^d\ [4] $$
$$ y+q=2^e\ [5]$$
$$ z+q=2^f\ [6] $$

After solving the first 4 equations we get:

$$x = 2^{a-1} + 2^{b-1} - 2^{d-1}\ [7]$$
$$y = 2^{a-1} + 2^{d-1} - 2^{b-1}\ [8]$$
$$z = 2^{b-1} + 2^{d-1} - 2^{a-1}\ [9]$$
$$q = 2^c - 2^{a-1} - 2^{b-1} + 2^{d-1}\ [10]$$

All nice and dandy. Let's continue with the last 2 equations. Replace y, z, and q with their other forms and get the following equations:

$$2^c+2^d-2^b = 2^e\ [11]$$
$$2^c+2^d-2^a = 2^f\ [12]$$

I conjectured that these equations have no nontrivial natural solutions.
So I asked it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538269/does-this-equation-have-any-natural-solutions/) on StackExchange and concluded it has none, just as suspected.

This means that the equations $[11]$ and $[12]$ have no valid solutions, and thus the (problem or) "square" with 4 integers cannot be completed.

Q.E.D.

But it seems too easy to be a complete and correct proof. I made some mistakes and it's not valid. I had fun playing around with it. I am curious to know where the mistakes are and why it's not valid.

**Note** that this proof can be generalized to any number of variables. The only exception where it doesn't work is for 2 variables ($x+y=2^a$ it works since there are infinitely many solutions), and for 3 variables, where the number of equations is equal to the number of variables.

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, this was noted at the end of the video itself, see https://www.numberphile.com/stop-press

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, but is my proof right? Does it have any mistakes?

Comment: The solutions only for those equations are $\{c,d\} = \{e,b\} = \{a.f\}$, and there's a nice graphical proof, that you can't get distinct $\{x,y,z,q\}$ when those hold.  So, baring any error in the computations (which I haven't fully checked), the proof seems correct.

Comment: It looks correct, actually all you need is $[4]-[1]+[3]$ to get $z+q=2^d-2^a+2^c$. And since $z+q=2^f$ you get $2^d+2^c=2^a+2^f$. Then either $f=d$ and $f=c$ and both lead to contradiction with the original numbers being distinct. I am honestly not sure why the original video claims this problem is open/impossible...

Comment: @Sil I agree. It's rather easy.

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding in what the original unsolved problem is. In the video he shows we can make 4 powers of 2, and this is the best known solution we can do. Getting all 6 pairs to be powers of 2 is impossible. The question is, can we do better? Is it possible to get 5 powers of 2? That would mean writing the equations out with one of the 6 equations not equal to a power of 2.

Comment: @Merosity That could be, even though in part of the video it seems to be explicitly said otherwise. But even then, the case of 5 powers of 2 is almost as easy as 6 to prove (I've added explanation in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems correct, however if you want to strip out unnecessary parts you can just evaluate $[4]-[1]+[3]$ to get $z+q=2^d-2^a+2^c$. Since $z+q=2^f$, you get $2^d+2^c=2^a+2^f$ and as you already noticed, then either $d=a$ or $d=f$. That means $y+z=2^d=2^a=x+y$ and $z=x$ (impossible), or $y+z=2^d=2^f=z+q$ and $y=q$ (again impossible).

This proves it is impossible to have all six pairs to be a powers of two. But, if you look close enough, you might notice we haven't used all equations (for example $[5]$ wasn't used at any point), so this is actually also proof for impossibility of five pairs.

Anyway as also pointed out in comments, after the video has been recorded there was a progress on the problem (including solution of the four numbers case) (https://www.numberphile.com/stop-press). It's probably not surprise that the proof uses the same idea as above.

Answer (score 1):

The two final equations can be deduced directly by the compatibility conditions of linear systems
$$\det\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0&0&2^a\\1&0&1&0&2^b\\1&0&0&1&2^c\\0&1&1&0&2^d\\1&1&0&1&2^e\end{vmatrix}=2(2^b-2^c-2^d+2^e)=0$$ and similarly with
$$\det\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0&0&2^a\\1&0&1&0&2^b\\1&0&0&1&2^c\\0&1&1&0&2^d\\0&0&1&1&2^f\end{vmatrix}=2(2^a-2^c-2^d+2^f)=0$$ from which
$$2^c+2^d=2^b+2^e=2^a+2^f$$ Taking for example,$$2^b+2^e=2^a+2^f$$ this is possible only when the minimum exponents in both sides are equal because if not we would have by division the false equality $odd=even$ but this implies the equality of the other exponents.

We are done.